# Custom UITableView sections being added more than once

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've made a custom class which adds a section header title and section content to a UITableViewCell.
I've managed to get the sections to show up but each section is added 5 times for some strange reason.

**Section Items Class**

```
  class MainSectionItems: SectionItems {
            override init() {
                //super.init()
            }
        }
        class SectionItems:NSObject{
            var sections:[String] = []
            var artists:[[String]] = []
            var songs:[[String]] = []
            var imgUrl: [[String]] = []
            func addSection(section: String, artist:[String], song: [String], imageUrl: [String]){
                sections += [section]
                artists = artists + [artist]
                songs = songs + [song]
                imgUrl = imgUrl + [imageUrl]
            }
        }
```

**MainViewController**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       getData{
                (msg) in
                self.menuItems.addSection("Featured Post", artist: self.artistArray, song: self.songNameArray, imageUrl: self.imgUrls)
              self.tVewCell.reloadData()
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    SwiftSpinner.hide()
                }
}
```

*getData is a method which retrieves 5 objects from parse.com*
**geData Function**

```
func getData ( completionHandler: (String) -> ()) -> () {
        let query = PFQuery(className:"chordBankA")
        query.orderByDescending("Artist")
        query.limit = 5
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                for object in objects! {
                    self.artistArray.append((object.objectForKey("Artist")) as! String)
                    self.songNameArray.append(((object.objectForKey("Song")) as! String))
                    self.imgUrls.append(((object.objectForKey("imgUrl")) as! String))
        completionHandler("0");
                }
            } else {
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
                completionHandler("1");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify few things - 1) What is there in `artistArray`, `songNameArray` & `imgUrls`. 2) How many times `getData ` gets called. 3) You said `getData ` retrieve 5 objects; I don't see that code. Please show that as well.

Comment: @Abhinav all strings. getData is called once in viewLoad. getData function has been added

Comment: I believe your issue is that you are calling your completion block inside for loop. Should this not be out side for loop once all your objects are set?

Comment: That resolved the issue. Thanks for your help @Abhinav

Comment: Glad it helped. I've posted my answer. Request you to please accept it for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for sharing `getData` code. Your issue is that you are calling your completion block inside for loop. Put it outside for loop and you should be good!